# Seting Wordpress on Centos7 using ansible

Tags: wordpress, ansible, mariadb, centos7

[☺ first time posting here, I have huge problems with formating so sorry, I really dont understand how to get that code to the grey  boxes, sorry!)
Hello, so I am supposed to set up a server using Ansible for a high school graduation project. All I have to do is basicaly install a few programs like htop, httpd ..... and finally set up a wordpress server. I am folowing this [guide](https://www.tecmint.com/automate-wordpress-installations-in-multiple-linux-servers-using-ansible/).

Problem is that this code:

```
---
# tasks file for wp-dependencies
- name: Update packages (this is equivalent to yum update -y)
  yum: name=* state=latest

- name: Install dependencies for WordPress
  yum:
    name:
        - php
        - php-mysql
        - MySQL-python
    state: present

- name: Ensure MariaDB is running (and enable it at boot)
  service: name=mariadb state=started enabled=yes

- name: Copy ~/.my.cnf to nodes
  copy: src=.my.cnf dest=/root/.my.cnf
- name: Create MariaDB database
  mysql_db: name={{ wp_mysql_db }} state=present

- name: Create MariaDB username and password
  mysql_user: login_user=root login_password=root name = {{ wp_mysql_user }} password = {{ wp_mysql_password }}
      priv=*.*:ALL`
```

Results in this error:

```
TASK [wp-dependencies : Create MariaDB username and password] ******************************************
fatal: [192.168.56.101]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "missing required arguments: user"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/Admin/wordpress.retry
```

COuld you tell whats the problem?

Comment: What program are you using to run the `Tasks` ?

Comment: So I got this file wordpress.yml, with 
`---  
- hosts: all  
  roles:  
        - wp-dependencies  
        - wp-install-config`
And i run it ansible-playbook wordpress.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task is this:

```
- name: Create MariaDB username and password
  mysql_user: login_user=root login_password=root name = {{ wp_mysql_user }} password = {{ wp_mysql_password }}
  priv=*.*:ALL`
```

You have spaces between `name` and `password` and the values they are to take.  And for safe variable handling you should also place quotation marks (") around the variables.

Try this:

```
- name: Create MariaDB username and password
  mysql_user: login_user=root login_password=root name="{{ wp_mysql_user }}" password="{{ wp_mysql_password }}" priv=*.*:ALL
```

Comment: Hi! Yeah that worked like a charm. THANK YOU, I really mean it.